# Bootstrap drowdown menu appears on the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make a simple dropdown menu with Bootstrap but it appears on the bottom of the page. What's going wrong?

```css
.dropdown-informatie {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.dropdown-pagina {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h1> Test </h1>
<p>Test</p>

<div class="dropdown-pagina">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Pagina's <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Pagina 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Pagina 2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Pagina 3</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-informatie">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Informatie <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">informatie 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">informatie 2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">informatie 3</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO... In order to give support and value to your question copy/paste the relevant code here ... Don't link outside to see the code

Comment: Tried doing that, kept saying there was to much code, i had to add text

Comment: add just the relevant part and if it's too much put all the code on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I just updated with an example of your working code at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YOUR NEW CODE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/PGmAvX)

Instead of using `"dropdown-pagina"` as a class you will need to use just `dropdown`. Then a second and third class for `pagina` and `informatie` can be made for specific styling as `dropdown` is a defined Bootstrap class.

The structure for a Bootstrap 3 drop down is as follows:

```css
div.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">                                   
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You should add another class to the `<div>` you are looking to style, i.e. `<div class="dropdown anotherClassForStyling">`